# Foreign key external ID not found

Tags: integration

Below is the snippet from the response that we receive to update/upsert a contact value from another system. Get a foreign key error on the account entity. The value is present on the account object (queried to find).

```
<tns:externalIDFieldName>Number__c</tns:externalIDFieldName>
            <tns:sObjects>
               <ens:type xmlns:ens="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">Contact</ens:type>
               <ens:SId__c xmlns:ens="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">12345678</ens:SId__c>
               <ens:Number__c xmlns:ens="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">12329065</ens:Number__c>
               <ens:StreetAddress__c xmlns:ens="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">47 GEORGE STREET</ens:StreetAddress__c>
               <ens:StreetAddress2__c xmlns:ens="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com"/>
               <ens:StreetAddress3__c xmlns:ens="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com"/>
               <ens:Account xmlns:ens="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
                  <ens:type>Account</ens:type>
                  <ens:AccId__c>12344445</ens:AccId__c>
               </ens:Account>
            </tns:sObjects>
```

> Foreign key external ID: 12344445 not found for field
>   AccId__c in entity Account
>                     INVALID_FIELD

Comment: Is that marked as external id?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have any field whose API Name is `AccId__c` on the `Account` object.

Comment: Yes, it is marked as an external ID and is unique. The API name of the field is AccId__c.

Comment: As mentioned, when I query for it, it does return the result, but strangely doesn't work via integration.

Comment: Does the integration user have access to the field?  Is there a namespace in the org?